# JavaFX Label double precision

Tags: java, javafx, precision

Currently, I'm practicing my JavaFX skills. Mostly, I'm trying to solve problem by myself, but this time it's out of my mind.

I decided to create a unit converter. Everything was OK until I wanted to get my calculations inside Labels Mine code works good, but I'm not happy to see 10 or more decimals when I input numbers like 155.54 etc.

Here's the code:

```
value = input.getText().toString();
dValue = Double.parseDouble(value);

    public void temperatureHandler() {
    if (cBox.getValue() == "Celsius (C)") {
        celsiusOutput.setText(Double.toString(dValue));
        fahrenheitOutput.setText(Double.toString((dValue * 1.8) + 32));
        kelvinOutput.setText(Double.toString(dValue + 273.15));
    }
    else if (cBox.getValue() == "Fahrenheit (F)") {
        celsiusOutput.setText(Double.toString((dValue - 32) / 1.8));
        fahrenheitOutput.setText(Double.toString(dValue));
        kelvinOutput.setText(Double.toString((dValue + 459.67) * 5/9));
    }
    else if (cBox.getValue() == "Kelvin (K)") {
        celsiusOutput.setText(Double.toString(dValue - 273.15));
        fahrenheitOutput.setText(Double.toString((dValue * 1.8) - 459.67));
        kelvinOutput.setText(Double.toString(dValue));
    }
}
```

I have some experience in using String formats, StringBuilders etc. But I have no idea how can I set precision inside Label. I want to set it to 2 decimals.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a decimal format to format / truncate your double to 2 decimal places..

## Example

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); 
df.format(myDouble);
```

in your case

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); 
celsiusOutput.setText(df.format((dValue - 32) / 1.8));
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I applied the changes, but it doesn't work. I tried many different ways, but it mostly ends up like this time: "The method toString(Double) in the type Double is not applicable for the arguments (String)". Any idea, how can I get rid of it. I'm sorry if I'm asking for obvious things, but I'm not the brightest star of programming :(

Comment: yes...remove the Double.tooString... you dont need it anymopre\